# How to re-trigger function whenever a variable is updated

Tags: swift, swiftui, eventkit

**UPDATED**

I'm pulling events from IOS calendar with EventKit. Working great.

Here's the class function that retrieves the events.

```
@ObservedObject var selectDate = datepicker() // does NOT update as expected.
```

```
func loadEvents(completion: @escaping (([EKEvent]?) -> Void)) {
    requestAccess(onGranted: {
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self.selectDate.selectedDate)
        let endOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self.selectDate.selectedDate.advanced(by: TimeInterval.day))
        let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startOfDay, end: endOfDay, calendars: Array(self.selectedCalendars ?? []))
        let events = self.eventStore.events(matching: predicate)

        completion(events)
        print("loadEvents triggered for \(self.selectDate.selectedDate)") // This ALWAYS returns the current date
    }) {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

I want to update the results based on a chosen date.
so I have a date picker assigned to a @ObservedObject var **selectDate** in my main view

```
@ObservedObject var selectDate = datepicker()
```

```
DatePicker(
    selection: $selectDate.selectedDate,
    in: dateClosedRange,
    displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute], label: { Text("Is hidden label") })
}
```

And this class is acting as the middle man. The `didSet` method is triggering the function to run, confirmed by the print statement in the `loadEvents` func above.

```
class datepicker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date() {
        didSet {
            print("class datepicker date changed to \(selectedDate)") // This returns the changed dates correctly
            EventsRepository.shared.loadAndUpdateEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the new date like this too.

```
let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: datepicker.init().selectedDate)
```

With the same persistent "current date" only result.

How can I pass the new selectedDate to the function whenever the **selectDate.selectedDate** from the datePicker is changed?

At the moment it doesn't update at all. Always returns events for the current day only.

The print statements contained in the above code in Debug return.

```
"class datepicker date changed to 2020-08-13 19:23:28 +0000" // YEP That's right. I used datePicker to select this date.
"loadEvents triggered for 2020-08-10 19:23:28 +0000" // NOT updated, ALWAYS shows current date/time as first run.
```

So it looks like @Published property is a constant and can not be changed once set. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I re-trigger the func loadEvents whenever the
> selectDate.selectedDate from the datePicker is changed?

You can try using `didSet`:

```
class datepicker: ObservableObject{
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date() {
        didSet {
            // loadEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.6, iOS 13.6.

---

**EDIT**

It looks like you're using **two** instances of `datepicker` object. Make sure you're using **the same instance** in all relevant places.

This object should only be created once:

```
@ObservedObject var selectDate = datepicker()
```

Then passed to other places in `init`.

Comment: This will definitely not work. The actual type here is `Published<>`, the property wrapper, which technically never gets set again.

Comment: @Procrastin8 No, you're wrong. Please run my code in the playground (you can `print` on `didSet`) and see what happens. I understand the *Combine* way may look better to you but please don't criticise my solution without testing it first.

Comment: I can confirm with print statements that the `didSet`method is triggering the functions to run. But the new chosen date is not being passed along to those functions. So it looks like `Published` is a one time deal as @Procrastin8 suggests. I've looked at the other proposed solution but have failed to implement it correctly ( I'm very much a novice so it's certainly my failing) But as `didSet` is getting the job done to trigger the function the only remaining problem is passing the new date. Is there another alternative to `Pubished`?

Comment: @My4Paws Hard to say exactly what you are doing. You can try passing `selectedDate` to `loadEvents` as a parameter.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thank you, I have updated the question to show better what's happenning.

Comment: @My4Paws Judging by your code, you're creating **two** instances of the `datepicker` object. So the `selectedDate` is updated. You're just referring to another instance. I updated my answer.

Comment: Did you mean like this `var selectDate = datepicker.init()` in the function class?  . If so the code compiles without error, but doesn't change the outcome. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219572/discussion-between-pawello2222-and-my4paws).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to actually subscribe to your own publisher when you create your model object.

```swift
class DateManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var selectedDate: Date = .init()

  private var bag: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

  init() {
    $selectedDate // $ prefix gets the projected value, a `Publisher` from `Published<>`
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink { [weak self] selectedDate in
        self?.loadEvents(date: selectedDate)
      }
      .store(in: &bag)
  }
}
```

This will subscribe to that publisher and trigger your API call when it changes. you can get fancy and add `debounce` or small delays if the user is rapidly changing dates, etc. you now have the full power of combine to control this data flow.